# How to append a url on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have an interesting dilemma that I am trying to resolve. I am using **FancyBox** and when using it, it requires that loading an `iframe` has an `href` tag and a `url` set.

In the present form, a user selects a square, and then enters in an amount, and then clicks a button - which fires (opens) fancybox.

What I would like it to do is to modify the `href url` each step of the way.

For example, starting `url` is say:

```
http://www.domain.com/do.php
```

On the `click` of the square, it then becomes

```
http://www.domain.com/do.php?s=3
```

Then on entering an amount the `url` appends to be:

```
http://www.domain.com/do.php?s=3&amount=20
```

I've found some references to changing a `url`, but they all seem to be changing the `url` for browser history. So I am wondering if anyone could lead me in the right direction so that I can accomplish this?

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you sending the data via $_GET?

Comment: Get or Post - doesn't matter really.

Comment: Have you looked into the `window.pushState` API ?

Comment: I don't believe that has to do with what I am trying to do. Unless I am wrong, that has to do directly with browser urls. That's not what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can append to the URL by using the below method:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btnGo" onclick="getUrl()"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getUrl() {
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    setUrl(currentUrl);
}

function setUrl(url) {
    var result = url + "?anotherargument";
    window.location.href = result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's close, but how do I approach the second call? That would set say ?s=3 but what about when it comes time for appending the amount so it becomes ?s=3&amount=10

Comment: I'd need to see your code to answer that. But, you should be able to just attach the `getUrl` function to any event handler on the events you need it fire on.

Comment: When the user enters the amount, do they click an 'enter' button or anything? What's the identifier that's used to know when a user has finished entering their amount?

Comment: And by the way, that seems to get the url of the browser if I am not mistaken, instead, I am looking to change the url in the current html code for the iframe and append to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link. That makes a little bit more sense. In this case, I wouldn't worry about appending to the URL as they click. I would just build up a string and once they select the person after they enter amount, then refresh the iframe to that final url. Would that work or is it kind of like the first click is filter data and the amount could be an optional second piece of filter data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86657/discussion-between-mrtechie-and-mwilson).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to reload the url of an Iframe.
There is simple javascript-only solution for that. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/2tf3vyLb/2/

Uploading `src` attribute of Iframe:

```
function appendToUrl(str){
    document.getElementById('f1').src += str;
}
```

in your case the parameter first is `?s=3`, second time `&amount=20`

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the href of the iframe?

Have you tried simply setting it like so

```
$('#square').click(function(){
   $('iframe').attr('href', $('iframe').attr('href') + '?s=3')
})

$('#amount_button').click(function(){
   $('iframe').attr('href', $('iframe').attr('href') + '&amount=' + $('#amount').val())
})
```

Comment: But what needs to happen is based on the user's interaction as well. So when they click the square, enter in an amount. Each one of those would make a separate call and append the url.